# Import error: cannot import name 'unicode_emo' from 'emot.emo_unicode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, emoji

I am trying to use emojis and used the code below but it keeps giving import error. I am using Jupyter notebook and have updated the anaconda. I also installed emot on conda cmd using
`pip install emot` still it shows the same import error.

```py
import re

from emot.emo_unicode import UNICODE_EMO,EMOTICONS
```

Comment: When you get an error message, you should share the error message. It helps others identify what the potential problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that imports with Jupyter Notebook cause a lot of troubles to people because Jupyter does use the same python environment as your console.

Follow [this link](https://modelpredict.com/importing-packages-in-jupyter-notebook/) to see ways of successfully import modules.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the [source file](https://github.com/NeelShah18/emot/blob/master/emot/emo_unicode.py) of `emot.emo_unicode`, and it seems like it only defines the following variables:

- `EMOTICONS_EMO`
- `EMOJI_UNICODE`
- `EMOJI_ALIAS_UNICODE`
- `UNICODE_EMOJI`
- `UNICODE_EMOJI_ALIAS`

These do not match the variables that you're importing, as neither `UNICODE_EMO` nor `EMOTICONS` is defined by this module. To fix this, you'll need to import the correct variables.

Answer (score 0):

The issue gets resolved if you try the below:

```
 from emot.emo_unicode import UNICODE_EMOJI # For emojis
 from emot.emo_unicode import EMOTICONS_EMO # For EMOTICONS
```

---

Answer (score 0):

for me it got resolved with

```
from emoji import EMOJI_DATA
```

earlier I was using UNICODE_EMO / ENICODE_EMOJI

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).